# Is there an objective method to know the degrees of nearsightedness or farsightedness?

Tags: eye, opthalmology, myopia-nearsightedness

Is there an objective method to know the degrees of nearsightedness or farsightedness? The current method for eye tests is to ask the patient to read numbers/letters, then the ophthalmologist puts lenses on the patient and asks him which one he sees better with. This is not an objective method because it depends on the person’s answers.

My question: Is it possible to make a physical examination for the reasons of nearsightedness/farsightedness (maybe cornea, eyeball length..etc) or does every person have different eye specs inside?

Comment: Is "scientific" the right word to describe what I mean ?

Comment: No, I don't think it's the right word. I edited your question to provide what I think is a better choice. If you disagree, you can revert my edits.